# comparing two arrays and get the values which are not common

Tags: python-3.x, list, duplicates, copy

I am doing this problem a friend gave me where you are given 2 arrays say (a[1,2,3,4] and b[8,7,9,2,1]) and you have to find not common elements. 
Expected output is [3,4,8,7,9]. Code below.

```
def disjoint(e,f):
c = e[:]
d = f[:]
for i in range(len(e)):
    for j in range(len(f)):
        if e[i] == f[j]:
            c.remove(e[i])
            d.remove(d[j])
final = c + d
print(final)

print(disjoint(a,b))
```

I tried with nested loops and creating copies of given arrays to modify them then add them but...

```
def disjoint(e,f):
c = e[:]                      # list copies
d = f[:]
for i in range(len(e)):
    for j in range(len(f)):
        if e[i] == f[j]:
            c.remove(c[i])     # edited this line
            d.remove(d[j])
final = c + d
print(final)

print(disjoint(a,b))
```

when I try removing common element from list copies, I get different output [2,4,8,7,9]. why ??
This is my first question in this website. I'll be thankful if anyone can clear my doubts.

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code to make it works:

```
def disjoint(e,f):
    c = e.copy() # [:] works also, but I think this is clearer
    d = f.copy()
    for i in e: # no need for index. just walk each items in the array
        for j in f:
            if i == j: # if there is a match, remove the match.
                c.remove(i)
                d.remove(j)
    return c + d

print(disjoint([1,2,3,4],[8,7,9,2,1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc5NCsIwEAXgdXKKB24aDAV/QC30AJ6hdKHJhKatSUlTxdPXtKgwDHwMb3jDOzbeHeZZk4G2Y@utixlJIwrOFEpQrvzwzgQ2qIoaLx@6Ebd@9BL3KeKK2FjXLXtEGtXTLVDgTKes@WY5Mz7AwjpQeruqXWQWMWvSrSzRrmIqD/TwT8qsWK1/bpMDxSk4KGyhOR/C0vZfu9rJvTzIYy2rszzJS9KuFmKePw)

There are a lot of more effecient way to achieve this. Check this stack overflow question to discover them: [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists). My favorite way is to use `set` (like in @newbie's answer). What is a `set`? Lets check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set):

> A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects. Common uses include membership testing, **removing duplicates from a sequence**, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and **symmetric difference**. (For other containers see the built-in dict, list, and tuple classes, and the collections module.)

*emphasis mine*

Symmetric difference is perfect for our need!

> Returns a new set with elements in either the set or the specified iterable but not both.

Ok here how to use it in your case:

```
def disjoint(e,f):
    return list(set(e).symmetric_difference(set(f)))

print(disjoint([1,2,3,4],[8,7,9,2,1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYxBCoNADEXXnVPM0kAoWAXbXkWkCyfBSB0lExeefpx24dv99@Fth01rbHIOxD5ImleJVhEyvN1NyXaN/ivJqkRFwz0dy0KmMn6CMJNSHOn/MQA4X3Cb/hJXq6/xgQ22A/ZP7PBVVj0A5HwC)

Answer (score 3):

Using `sets` you can do:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [8,7,9,2,1]
diff = (set(a) | set(b)) - (set(a) & set(b))
```

`(set(a) | set(b))` is the union, `set(a) & set(b)` is the intersection and finally you do the difference between the two sets using `-`.

Your bug comes when you remove the elements in the lines `c.remove(c[i])` and `d.remove(d[j])`. Indeed,  the common elements are `e[i]`and `f[j]` while `c` and `d` are the lists you are updating.
To fix your bug you only need to change these lines to `c.remove(e[i])` and `d.remove(f[j])`.

Note also that *your method to delete items in both lists will not work if a list may contain duplicates*.
Consider for instance the case `a = [1,1,2,3,4]` and `b = [8,7,9,2,1]`.

Comment: I was trying to refrain from using functions but its good to see the approaches anyway