# How to get difference between two lists using sets

Tags: python, list, set

Why does this work:

```
a = ["one", "two","three"]
b = ["one","three"]
c = set(a)-set(b)
d = set(b)-set(a)
e = []
e.append(d)
e.append(c)
```

And this does not:

```
example = set(set([a])-set([b])) + set(set([b])-set([a]))
```

I know, the first case, would produce a different result than the second one, regarding amount of indexes.

How could I make the second version using set, without using union or symbol items.

Desired output: Make a final list, where you get:

```
output = ["two"]
```

Basically finding the element that isn't in common using only set functions and making it a one liner.

Comment: Why not just `set(a).symmetric_difference(b)`?

Comment: I don't understand why you have those two extra set calls. Why not just `(set([a])-set([b])) + (set([b])-set([a])`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman If I do so, I get this: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 0):

It's a silly error:

```
>>> a=["one", "two", "three"]
>>> set(a)
set(['three', 'two', 'one'])
>>> set([a])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Note the difference between the two calls to `set()`: one passes the list, the other makes a list containing a sublist and passes that.

(Once you fix that, you will have to address the fact that you cannot *add* sets:

> without using union

the `+` operator is not defined on sets but if it were it would probably be a union operator.)

Comment: If I do so:  `(set(a)-set(b)) + (set(b)-set(a))`
I am getting **unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'set' and 'set'**

Comment: Right, because sets do not support addition. (What, mathemtatically, is {2, 3} + {orange} if not union?) Note that Python *does* let you *add* lists, constructing a new list consisting of the appending of the two.

Comment: right, but why does this work? `set(list(s) + list(t))` and how I could implement that into my code?

Comment: You can convert any set to a list using `list`, and any list of hashtable items to a set (dropping duplicates) using `set`, since the `list` and `set` constructors take any iterable. That's what you do in your working sample. So, to make a one-liner out of it, consider doing just that.

Comment: BTW this particular question looks like a homework assignment, which is probably why no one else is providing a one-liner either. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One liner:

```
list(set(a) - set(b)) # ["two"]
```