# How to compare string value list inside list.Python

Tags: python

How to compare string in list

```
a = [['abc','Hello World'],['bcd','Hello Python']]
b = [['abc','Hello World'],['bcd','Hello World'],['abc','Python World']]
```

I want to compare every value between two lists.
For one, I want result to be (values in b but not in a):

```
[['bcd','Hello World'],['abc','Python World']]
```

Other one to be (values in a but not in b):

```
['bcd','Hello Python']
```

Comment: Convert the lists of lists to sets of tuples, then you are half-way done.

Comment: I need specific help...First time in coding..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Convert your lists of lists to sets of tuples (you can't have sets of lists, as sets can only contain [hashable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) objects, which lists, as all built-in mutable objects, are not)

```
a = set(map(tuple, [['abc','Hello World'],['bcd','Hello Python']]))
b = set(map(tuple, [['abc','Hello World'],['bcd','Hello World'],['abc','Python World']]))
```

or create them directly as sets of tuples:

```
a = {('abc','Hello World'),('bcd','Hello Python')}
b = {('abc','Hello World'),('bcd','Hello World'),('abc','Python World')}
```

You can then easily and efficiently get your differences:

```
print(b - a)
# {('abc', 'Python World'), ('bcd', 'Hello World')}

print(a - b)
# {('bcd', 'Hello Python')}
```

or even the intersection

```
print(a & b)
# {('abc', 'Hello World')}
```

or the union:

```
print(a | b)
# {('abc', 'Python World'), ('bcd', 'Hello World'), ('abc', 'Hello World'), ('bcd', 'Hello Python')}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a quick solution without much concerns about performance you can use

```
b_not_in_a = [i for i in b if i not in a]
a_not_in_b = [i for i in a if i not in b]
```