# finding which element is wrong in list(python)

Tags: python-3.x

I have two lists, `englishclub` and `listofallclub`

I have already checked that not all elements in `englishclub` are in `listofallclub`, but I want to find which element is missing from `listofallclub`

I expect the lists to be very large.

```
listallclub = df.Club.tolist()

result =  all(elem in englishclub  for elem in  listallclub)

if result:
    print("Yes, englishclub  contains all elements in listallclub")    
else :
    print("No, englishclub  does not contains all elements in listallclub")
```

I would like my outputto be the list of elements that are in `englishclub` but not in `listofallclub`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: show us what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

`other_clubs = [e for e in listallclub if e not in englishclub]`

Comment: Hi! While this may be an answer to the question (untested), code only answers are discouraged on SO. Please consider adding an explanation to your answer to help OP better understand, and to provide greater benefit to future visitors of the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension,

```
e = [ec for ec in englishclub if ec not in listallclub]

if e:
    print("No, englishclub  does not contains all elements in listallclub")
    print("And they are")
    print(e)
else :
    print("Yes, englishclub  contains all elements in listallclub")
```