# How to extract list between 2 list python 3?

Tags: python

How to map and append values from one list to other list python 3?

```
in_put_1 = [["a alphanum2 c d"], ["g h"]] 
in_put_2 = [["e f"], [" i j k"]]

output = ["a alphanum2 c d e f", "g h i j k"]
```

Comment: is the output a flat list? the output must be sorted? by individual element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi this isn't asking for diff, it's merging them

Comment: it should be merged and no sorting

Comment: why do you need array of single string? is it comma separated?

Comment: no comma separated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can concatenate the strings in the sublists together while iterating over the two lists together using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), stripping the individual strings to get rid of surrounding whitespaces in the process

```
[f'{x[0].strip()} {y[0].strip()}' for x, y in zip(in_put_1, in_put_2)]
```

To do it without zip, we would need to explicitly use indexes to access elements in the list

```
result = []
for idx in range(len(in_put_1)):

    s = f'{in_put_1[idx][0].strip()} {in_put_2[idx][0].strip()}'
    result.append(s)
```

The output will be

```
['a alphanum2 c d e f', 'g h i j k']
```

Answer (score 4):

```
>>>map(lambda x,y: x[0]+" "+y[0],in_put_1,in_put_2)
['a alphanum2 c d e f', 'g h  i j k']
```

Comment: N.B. In Python 3, `map` returns a generator and needs to be converted to list first before obtaining the output in the form of a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
[' '.join(element1+element2) for (element1,element2) in zip(in_put_1,in_put_2) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [["a alphanum2 c d"], ["g h"]] 
b = [["e f"], [" i j k"]]
c = []
for (a1, b1) in zip(a,b): 
     c.append(''.join([str(a) + b for a,b in zip(a1,b1)]))
print(c)
```