# List comprehension fails with two set difference objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I got two sets and want to add the differences to a list with a list comprehension.

Using one set works perfectly fine:
`diff = [x for x in a.difference(b)]`

However, when I try to include the second set (b) I get already a warning from PyCharm that the **syntax is invalid**.

Error message:

```
    diff = [x,y for x in a.difference(b) for y in b.difference(a)]
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Below is a web example and the comparative attempt with my input which creates lists within the `diff` list which I do not want.

Web Example: `my_list = [x * y for x in [20, 40, 60] for y in [2, 4, 6]]`

`diff = [[x,y] for x in a.difference(b) for y in b.difference(a)]`

Output: `[[9, 11], [9, 12], [5, 11], [5, 12]]`

Expected Output: `[5,9,11,12]`

**What is the syntax to create one list with the set differences from two sets?**

Comment: shorter `diff = list(a.difference(b))`

Comment: Are you after [`set.symmetric_difference`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.symmetric_difference) ?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists

Comment: @SillyFreak, yes, your link solves the issue but I am more interested why the list comprehension does not work (as I would expect it).

Comment: you have syntax error because of comma between `x,y` - Python can't add two elements at once to list comprehension.

Comment: @furas, thank you. This answered my question.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you need `list(a.difference(b)) + list(b.difference(a))`

Comment: @furas, thank you for your example. I will work with it!

Comment: o maybe `list( a.difference(b) | b.difference(a) )` or simply `list( a ^ b )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this from within the list comprehension–each element it returns is its own entity–but you can use itertools's [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) to get what you want:

```py
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((x,y) for x in a.difference(b) for y in b.difference(a))
```

The `list` call is there because the chain functions just return lazy iterators. If that is ok with you, you can remove the `list`.

Comment: I'd advise against this answer. Getting to the difference by flattening the list of pairs OP got is backwards, and also introduces duplicates. @Alex_P, take a look at jferard's answer, it has a number of ways that are way clearer and more direct than this one.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are looking for the symmetric difference:

```
>>> a = set([1,2,3,9,5])
>>> b = set([1,2,3,11,12])
>>> a ^ b
{5, 9, 11, 12}
```

Or:

```
>>> a.symmetric_difference(b)
{5, 9, 11, 12}
```

If you want to do it with `difference` and `union`:

```
>>> a.difference(b).union(b.difference(a))
{9, 11, 12, 5}
```

Or:

```
>>> (a-b) | (b-a)
{9, 11, 12, 5}
```

To transform a `set` into a `list`:

```
>>> list(a ^ b)
[5, 9, 11, 12]
```

For a set comprehension method:

```
>>> set(x for t,u in [(a,b), (b,a)] for x in t if x not in u)
{9, 11, 12, 5}
```

It takes every element in `a` that is not in `b` then every element in `b` that is not in `a`.

Comment: the last one seems unnecessarily convoluted... but very comprehensive list of options!

Comment: @SillyFreak the last one is there because of the `list-comprehension` tag, but you are right: I would never use it since higher level functions are available.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down what the list comprehension is very roughly syntactic sugar for:

```
diff = []
for x in a.difference(b):
    for y in b.difference(a):
        diff.append([x,y])
```

The two `for`s are nested! I've added the brackets around `x,y` to make it a single value so that it works, like it is necessary in the list comprehension. I hope this explains why you got `[[9, 11], [9, 12], [5, 11], [5, 12]]`: one difference was `{9, 5}`, the other was `{11, 12}`. The result is the cartesian product of those sets, as a list.

What you want is basically a union. In "desugared" list comprehensions, that would be a sequence of for loops:

```
diff = []
for x in a.difference(b):
    diff.append(x)
for y in b.difference(a):
    diff.append(y)
```

The other answers, comments, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists) already show how to achieve what your ultimate goal is, so I won't repeat that, but this is why your code didn't do what you thought it should.