# Compare two list and add all the unique elements to a new list

Tags: python-3.x

```
subs = ['Py', 'Jupyter', 'Spy', 'VisualStudio']
test_list = ['Python', 'Jupyter Notebook', 'Spyder',] 
set1=set(subs)
set2=set(test_list)
print(list(set2 - set1))
```

Actual Output 
['Python', 'Spyder', 'Jupyter Notebook']

Expected Output 
['Jupyter Notebook', 'Python', 'Spyder','VisualStudio']

**Solution**

```
test_list=['Python', 'Jupyter Notebook', 'Spyder',]
subs=['Py', 'Jupyter', 'Spy', 'VisualStudio']
set_sub=set(subs)
tem=[]
for elem in subs:
    for n in test_list:
        if elem not in n:
            continue
        tem.append(elem)
print(list(set(tem)),'\n\n')
set_tem=set(tem)
print(set_sub - set_tem )
list_diff=list(set_sub - set_tem)
for s in list_diff:
    test_list.append(s)
print(test_list)
```

This is the solution I was expecting.
Thank you everyone for helping me.

Comment: Can you post some more information?

Comment: This seems like a question related to competitive programming, even if it's not, try to include more details which makes it more easier for everyone to understand the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you took difference, that is `list(set2 - set1)`, it will result in those elements in your set2 which are not in set1
If you want to explore more about list difference you can checkout this existing [stackover question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists).

Example :

```
s1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
s2 = [2, 3, 5]
print(set(s1) - set(s2)) ==> {1, 4}
```

What you can do for your query is something like this :

```
tmp_set = set(set1 + set2) ==> This will contains unique elements from both set1 and set2
print([*tmp_set, ])
```

Your final code will look like this:

```
set1 = ['Py', 'Jupyter', 'Spy', 'VisualStudio']
set2 = ['Python', 'Jupyter Notebook', 'Spyder',] 
tmp_set = set(set1 + set2)
print([*tmp_set, ])
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation which matches the title `symmetric_difference` rather than `difference` (which is what `set - set` does): `difference` gives you all the elements of the first set which are not in the second, `symmetric_difference` gives you all the elements which are in either set but not both.

The operator for `symmetric_difference` is `^`.

However that would not yield your "expected output": your two lists don't share any element, so the symmetric difference will be all items as it works by equality.

If you want something more complicated (e.g. all elements which are not prefixes of an other) you will have to hand-roll it using a loop or a set comprehension.