# python lists, delete content of list1 in list2

Tags: python, list

I have two lists

```py
list1=['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
list2=['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']
```

I want to delete the contents of list1 from list2

Result should be :

```py
['value4', 'value5']
```

Comment: Do you want to remove those elements from the existing list, or create a new, filtered list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by converting the list1 to set and then by list comprehension create a new list with the items from list2 that not in list1

```
list1=['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
list2=['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']
list1_set = set(list1)
result = [i for i in list2 if i not in list1_set]
print(result)
```

Output

```
['value4', 'value5']
```

The conversion of list1 to set is from better performances since checking if an item is in a set is faster than in a list.

Answer (score 2):

`list2 = [elem for elem in list2 if elem not in list1]`

Comment: Technically, this does not _remove_ from `list2` but overwrite the variable with a new list. You could e.g. use `list[:] = ...` to replace all elements in `list2`. Also, converting `list1` to `set` might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

To print the values of items in list2 that are not in list1, you can use this code:

```
list1=['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
list2=['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']

print([list2 for list2 in list2 if list2 not in list1])
```

Comment: Note, this works, but is inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1=['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
list2=['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']

set_list_1 = set(list1)
set_list_2 = set(list2)
print(list(set_list_2.difference(set_list_1)))
['value4', 'value5']
```