# Find equivalent words from 2 strings

Tags: python, string

I have two strings 'I go to school and play badminton in the evening' and 'I go to **e2** and **r2** in the evening'. How to find **e2** = 'school' and **r2** = 'play badminton'. I tried using for loops but looking for a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: What if the string is 'I go to school and swim and play badminton in the evening'?

Comment: Yes it is possible. in that case, e2=school and r2=swim and play badminton

Comment: Why would r2 include "in the evening" then? And why wouldn't e2 include the "and swim" instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that pattern may change every time along with the string it turns out to be a string compare problem. Quite elegant solution may be provided with use of `difflib`.

```
str1 = "I go to e2 and r2 in the evening"
str2 = "I go to school and play badminton in the evening"

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
s = SequenceMatcher(None, str1, str2)
diff = [(str1[opcode[1]:opcode[2]], str2[opcode[3]:opcode[4]])
        for opcode in s.get_opcodes() if opcode[0] == 'replace']
print(diff)
# [('e2', 'school'), ('r2', 'play badminton')]
```

**Previous solution:**
I think most apropriate and flexible in this case would be using regex search.

```
import re
pattern = "I go to (.*) and (.*) in the evening"
string = "I go to school and play badminton in the evening"
m = re.match(pattern, string)
e2 = m.groups()[0]
r2 = m.groups()[1]
result = e2 == 'school' and r2 == 'play badminton'
print(result)
```

Comment: The pattern may change everytime along with the string.

Comment: I answered your question. It's not specified in your question how pattern may change. Please clarify it or provide example.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. Phrases like 'e2' or 'r2' or other apper explicitly in a text in various places - right?

Answer (score 2):

```
a = set('I go to school and play badminton in the evening'.split(' '))
b = set('I go to and in the evening'.split(' '))

print(a - b)
>>> {'badminton', 'school', 'play'}
```

**edit for your edit:**

If you would also like to name them directly from the parsing, you would need to tweak the input a bit and probably also use: [Does Python have an ordered set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653970/does-python-have-an-ordered-set)

Comment: The question has changed.

Comment: @Curious Just so I can know how to further edit my Answer: 1.Can you manipulate the input? 2.Are the name important?

Comment: Kindly read the question again. You must have not read the recent edit.

Comment: @Curious I did read your edit, but I want further clarification in order to **help you**

Comment: You cannot manipulate the input. Names are not important

Comment: @Curious Check the regex comment here, does it satisfy you?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "I go to school and play badminton in the evening"
b = "I go to and in the evening" 
a_set = set(a.split())
b_set = set(b.split())
print(a_set.difference(b_set))
# {'badminton', 'school', 'play'}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.