# How do you check if anything is new in a list? (python)

Tags: python

I would like to know how to check if anything is new in a list, like this:

```py
list_1 = [10, 30, 25]
list_2 = get_updated_list()
new_items = get_new_items(list_2)
if new_items is not []:
    print('Something is new')
```

I would highly appreciate it if someone had a solution, I've been thinking on how to do this for so long.

Comment: New compared to what? list_1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just care about the sets of values in `list_1` and `list_2`, without regard to their order or the number of times they occur, then you can use a simple set difference:

```
>>> list_1 = [10, 30, 25]
>>> list_2 = [10, 25, 45]
>>> list(set(list_2) - set(list_1))
[45]
>>>
```

This example shows the values that are present in `list_2` but not in `list_1`.  To see values that were removed, you can reverse the subtraction.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built-in set difference.

```
s1 = set(list_1)
s2 = set(list_2)

diff = s1.difference(s2)
if diff:
    print("Something is new")
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way, just do `-` and convert back to list:

```
list(set(list2)-set(list1))
```

Comment: But what if list_1 for instance is [0, 2, 2, 5]?