# Detecting which item in a list that is replaced

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to detect which item in a list that is replaced while ignoring occurance in the list, suppose I have:

```
before_list = ['C1', 'C16', 'C23', 'C14', 'C23', 'C13', 'C11', 'C19', 'C27', 'C10', 'C16', 'C28', 'C11', 'C8', 'C2', 'C27', 'C18', 'C27']

after_list = ['C1', 'C16', 'C23', 'C23', 'C13', 'C11', 'C19', 'C10', 'C16', 'C28', 'C8', 'C18', 'C27', 'C1', 'C14', 'C22', 'C16', 'C6']
```

I want to detect which item has been replaced by comparing `before_list` and `after_list`, and produce a list of the replaced item

```
to_be_replaced = ['C27','C11','C2','C27']
replace_with = ['C1','C22','C16','C6']
```

Can anyone help me with how to do this?

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @JohnColeman: As wonderful as `zip` is, it isn't the solution to this problem.

Comment: Where is `C14->Nothing` replacement (4th element in source list was removed) in your "result"?

Comment: @ScottHunter I misread it. I was thinking of parallel replacements of equal size lists. In effect, these are more like multi-sets than lists.

Comment: `set(before_list) - set(after_list)` will give you the elements only in the first list, subtracting the `after_list_set` from the `before_list_set` will give you what's in the second list and not in the first.

Comment: @MatsLindh: How will that handle duplicates?

Comment: @PatrickArtner: `C14` is in both source lists.

Comment: @ScottHunter it won't. I didn't read any decent specification about that in the question as it leaves a lot of details to be assumed. Which is why I added it as a comment, and not as an answer.

Comment: Since you don't care about order of occurrences, there will be multiple solutions. What criteria, if any, do you use to pick between multiple solutions? The problem seems unclear as stated. You could use `Counter` on both lists to abtain the sublists where the counts differ.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following gives one solution:

```
from collections import Counter
before_list = ['C1', 'C16', 'C23', 'C14', 'C23', 'C13', 'C11', 'C19', 'C27', 'C10', 'C16', 'C28', 'C11', 'C8', 'C2', 'C27', 'C18', 'C27']

after_list = ['C1', 'C16', 'C23', 'C23', 'C13', 'C11', 'C19', 'C10', 'C16', 'C28', 'C8', 'C18', 'C27', 'C1', 'C14', 'C22', 'C16', 'C6']

counts1 = Counter(before_list)
counts2 = Counter(after_list)
to_be_replaced = []
replace_with = []
for x,c1 in counts1.items():
  c2 = counts2[x]
  if c2 < c1:
    to_be_replaced.extend([x]*(c1 - c2))
for y,c2 in counts2.items():
  c1 = counts1[y]
  if c1 < c2:
    replace_with.extend([y] * (c2 - c1))
```

Which yields

```
to_be_replaced = ['C11', 'C27', 'C27', 'C2']
replace_with = ['C1', 'C16', 'C22', 'C6']
```

Answer (score 1):

This produces the desired lists (if not in the order specified):

```
i,j = 0,0
bl = sorted(before_list)
al = sorted(after_list)
tbr =[]
rw = []
while i<len(before_list) and j<len(after_list):
    if bl[i]<al[j]:
        tbr.append(bl[i])
        i += 1
    elif bl[i]>al[j]:
        rw.append(al[j])
        j += 1
    else:
        i += 1
        j += 1
```