# Removing a lot of elements from a large Python list while preserving the order of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Say I have two lists with 100,000 elements each and I want to find the set difference but keep the order of the elements. Example:

```
A = [10, 1, 30, 4, 5, 6]
B = [4, 1, 100]
```

desired output:

```
AB = [10, 30, 5, 6]
```

`set(A).difference(set(B))` is producing `[10, 5, 6, 30]` (notice how it doesn't preserve the order in `A`) and list comprehension is taking some time (I think it's because of the `in` operator).

Comment: Does this help : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists) answered by @markbyers

Answer (score 0):

Once you got the set difference, you can compare it with the original list order wise, and then save the result accordingly

```
A = [10, 1, 30, 4, 5, 6]
B = [4, 1, 100]
C = set(A).difference(set(B))
result = [item for item in A if item in C]
```

output

```
[10, 30, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions

`A = [x for x in A if x not in B]`