# How to subtract a list from a list?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a code that will subtract a list from a list.

For example:

```
list1 = ['hi', 'hi', 'once', 'twice']
list2 = ['hi', 'once', 'twice']
```

The result from the subtraction of the lists that I want is:

```
differenceoflists = ['hi']
```

Currently, I'm using the code

```
list1 = ['hi', 'hi', 'once', 'twice']
list2 = ['hi', 'once', 'twice']
differenceoflists = []
for i in list1:
    if i not in list2:
        differenceoflists.append(i)
print(differenceoflists)
```

However, this code doesn't function the way I want it to. It returns an empty list when I want it to return `['hi']`. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: But `'hi'` is in `list2`, so it cannot be in `differenceoflists`. Why do you expect it to be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists

Comment: Well, there's two hi's in list1, and there's only one in list2, so I'd like the code to count the extra hi in list1.

Comment: It's returning an empty list because the same '`hi'` in `list2` is being matched twice.  Depending on your performance and output constraints, you might be able to use your idea except work off of a *copy* of list2, and remove things from list2 using `.remove(item)` as you add them to the `differenceoflists`.

Answer (score 4):

This can also be done using `collections.Counter` you can subtract Counters from each-other then just turn the result into a list:

```
from collections import Counter

list1 = ['hi', 'hi', 'once', 'twice']
list2 = ['hi', 'once', 'twice']

difference_of_lists = list((Counter(list1) - Counter(list2)).elements())

print(difference_of_lists)
```

---

```
['hi']
```

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel with a generator expression you can call the [`elements`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) method of a `Counter` object to convert it to a list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work correctly because it does not keep track of *how often* an item from `list2` has been used to discard a corresponding item from `list1`.

Instead of building the `differenceoflists` by *adding* items, you can create it by starting with a copy of `list1` and *removing* all items from `list2`. That way, corresponding pairs of items are matched exactly once, and if an item is contained more often in `list1` than it is in `list2`, the extras will remain.

To remove an item from a list you can use the `remove` method. You need to handle the case when the item you try to remove isn't in the list (by just ignoring it).

```
def differenceoflists(list1, list2):
    d = list1.copy()
    for i in list2:
        try:
            d.remove(i)
        except ValueError:
            pass  # ignore that i is not in list1
    return d
```

There are some subtle differences in the order in which the items are contained in the result when comparing this code with the code shown in [Jab's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66359554). Depending on your exact needs you need to choose one or the other.

`differenceoflists` removes items from the left, while `differenceoflists_jab` removes items from the right:

```
>>> differenceoflists([1, 3, 5, 1], [5, 1])
[3, 1]
>>> differenceoflists([1, 3, 5, 1], [1, 5])
[3, 1]
>>> differenceoflists_jab([1, 3, 5, 1], [5, 1])
[1, 3]
>>> differenceoflists_jab([1, 3, 5, 1], [1, 5])
[1, 3]
```

`differenceoflists_jab` does not preserve the order of the items in `list1`:

```
>>> differenceoflists([1, 3, 5, 1], [5])
[1, 3, 1]
>>> differenceoflists_jab([1, 3, 5, 1], [5])
[1, 1, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it work if you didn't use the 'try'?

Comment: No, if there is an item in `list2` that is not in `list1`, trying to remove it will raise a `ValueError` exception.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!