# Comparing two lists with specific values to read

Tags: python, list, compare

I have two lists

```
list1 = ['01:15', 'abc', '01:15', 'def', '01:45', 'ghi' ]
list2 = ['01:15', 'abc', '01:15', 'uvz', '01:45', 'ghi' ]
```

and when I loop through the list

```
list_difference = []
for item in list1:
    if item not in list2:
        list_difference.append(item)
```

and I managed to get the difference, but I need time as well
because it is a separate item and `'uvz'` does not mean to me anything in the list with a few thousand entries.
I tried to convert it to the dictionary, but it overwrites with the last key:value `{'01:15' : 'def'}`.

Comment: What is your expected outcome?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists

Comment: If I understand correctly, the lists are pairs of timestamp-event. And you want to print both the events that are in the first list and not the second, and the timestamp associated with them?

Comment: Convert it to a list of tuples `[('01:15', 'abc'), ('01:15', 'def'), ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reformat your data, then do whatever you have done before

```
list1=list(zip(list1[::2],list1[1::2]))
list2=list(zip(list2[::2],list2[1::2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the two lists to sets of tuples, then use the set difference operator.

```
set1 = set((list1[i], list1[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(list1), 2))
set2 = set((list2[i], list2[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(list2), 2))
list_difference = list(set1 - set2)
```