# how to do roles logging in discord.py?

Tags: python, logging, discord, discord.py

I want to do role logging in discord.py, example:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after)
 await channel.send(after.role)
```

so it will send the after role(the new role), but after doesn't have `after.role` that will return the new role
so how do i get the new role name and id?

Answer (score 1):

Since `after.roles` returns a list and `before.roles`, you can check what changed using:

```py
changed_role_set = set(before.roles) ^ set(after.roles)
if len(changed_role_set) > 0
    changed_role = next(iter(changed_role_set))
    #and then answer
    await channel.send(f"The role {changed_role.name} got either removed or added to the user {after.name}")
```

---

**References**

- [check difference between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38240169/14506951)
- [member.roles](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.roles)