# How to find points in scipy KDTree between two radii of a position

Tags: python, kdtree, scipy-spatial

I have a set of locations in a KDTree object and I need to efficiently find the points that are more than r1 but less than r2 distance away

Is there a better way than:

```
idx_1 = kd_tree.query_ball_point(pos, r1)
idx_2 = kd_tree.query_ball_point(pos, r2)
# ...
idx_n = kd_tree.query_ball_point(pos, rn)
```

and then iterating over all the lists and popping out the indices or iterating through each point and checking for range?

```
KDTree.query()
```

Will provide indices and their distances but you have to specify the number of points to return which is not predictable.

Edit: I think I found an easy way to partition out indices via this solution: [Get difference between two lists with Unique Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462143/get-difference-between-two-lists-with-unique-entries?rq=2)

but it still requires running KDTree.query_ball_point() multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You didn't describe any aspects of the Business Domain
that are motivating your use case.

[WLOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality)
let's consider some 2-D bullseyes.
Given r1=40 and r2=50, we seek an unknown number
of matching points in an annulus of width ten.

Drop a circle onto the X axis, centered on (45, 0).
Choose some convenient radius, greater than five.
Theta is zero, that is, pointing along the X axis.
Increase theta so we can drop another such circle,
completely covering the next portion of the annulus.
Continue dropping circular search regions until
we have returned to our starting point.
Issue `.query_ball_point()` queries for each of them,
and filter by `r1 < r < r2` to obtain the final results.

In higher dimensional spaces this can lead to an
annoyingly large number of queries,
which possibly is balanced by sparse volumes
that offer zero result points.
Based on just the assumptions outlined in OP,
it's unclear whether this approach would
be winning, compared to simple difference of
a pair of result sets.

---

A single query for `r2` suffices.
Then examine each result point,
filtering them against the `r1` criterion.

This may run faster than issuing a pair of queries.

Comment: This is really clever however I think it will result in more computations than the brute forcing it akin to my problem statement, especially because my annulus width will be constant but each concentric circle will be bigger and bigger so theta will have to keep getting smaller

Comment: Well, it’s a trade-off, right? The part that I sidestepped was specifying the radius. With small annulus width, it may still be worthwhile to specify a moderately large radius, to keep the total number of queries manageable. The relevant metric  is the ratio of r2 divided by r1. But yeah, absent timing measurements it’s hard to say, and I suspect that “simple” wins. We would need impressively rapid returns of “zero matching points” for large empty regions, when that ratio is inconveniently small.