# How to check if an element from List A is not present in List B in Python?

Tags: python, list

If I have one element alone this is easy:

```
>>> 3 not in [2, 3, 4]
False
>>> 3 not in [4, 5, 6]
True
```

But what if I have two lists and have to check if the elements in list `A` occur in list `B`?

```
A=[1,2,3,4]
B=[4,5,6,7]
```

How do I get a results showing me that `1`,`2`,`3` are not in list `B`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding elements not in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104305/finding-elements-not-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension:

truthy answer

```
any([True for x in [1, 2, 3, 4] if x in [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

list of elements not present in the second list

```
[x for x in [1, 2, 3, 4] if x not in [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, so that the asker can understand how it works.

Comment: what if element repeated ?

Answer (score 8):

if the items in the list are *hashable*:

```
>>> set(A) - set(B)
{1, 2, 3}
```

otherwise, you may use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda a: a not in B, A))
[1, 2, 3]
```

in that case, if `B` is *sorted*, you may get a better performance by using [`bisect.bisect_left`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/bisect.html#bisect.bisect_left) to search logarithmically:

```
>>> def pred(a):  # if B is already *sorted*
...     from bisect import bisect_left
...     i = bisect_left(B, a)
...     return i == len(B) or B[i] != a
... 
>>> list(filter(pred, A))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use list comprehension:

```
C=[i for i in A if i not in B]
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set(A).difference(B) # set operation for difference between two collections A and B
```

Comment: Just to point out that this is not the symmetric difference. `set(A).difference(B)` will yield a different result than `set(B).difference(A)` when the lists are not exactly equal. If B contains a subset of A, then the latter will result an empty set. `set(A).symmetric_difference(B)` yields the same as `set(B).symmetric_difference(A)`. Here is a good link: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/difference

Answer (score 1):

That's a typical case for boolean operations on sets:

```
zerotonine = set(range(10))
fourtoten = set(range(4,11))
print "exclusively in one:", zerotonine ^ fourtoten
exclusively in one: set([0, 1, 2, 3, 10])
```

Comment: Just to point out: This is the same as using `set(A).symmetric_difference(B)` which has the same result as `set(B).symmetric_difference(A)`. Be aware that `set(A).difference(B)` could return a different result than `set(B).difference(A)` ("In A but not in B" vs "In B but not in A"), in case you're after such a property (as the question's title might suggest)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set`.

e.g.

```
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=[4,5,6,7]
>>> list(set(a)-set(b))
[1, 2, 3]
>>>
```