# about basic Python list indexing

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm not sure if this has been asked before as it seems to be a simple question, I tried to search it but did not find a very good answer.

Say I have a list of numbers `a`. I know I can get out every fifth number by `a[::5]`.

What should be the simplest way to get the rest of the list (items in `a` but not in `a[::5]`)?

**Edit**:
this is not the same question as [Finding elements not in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104305/finding-elements-not-in-a-list) as I already know that the rest of the list consists of `a[1::5]+a[2::5]+a[3::5]+a[4::5]`, I'm just asking is there a simpler way / syntax sugar for that?

**Edit**:
Thank you all for answering.
Is there a solution without scanning over the whole list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding elements not in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104305/finding-elements-not-in-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[x for i, x in enumerate(a) if i % 5 != 0]`

`not in set(a[::5])` will not work correctly when list contains equal elements. `not in a[::5]` is also not optimal from performance point of view.

**Edit** There is no syntactic sugar for your problem in Python. Take a look at numpy: it has extensive slicing possibilities.

**Edit** To avoid list scanning, you could create wrapper class with `__getitem__` method.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by something like:

```
[v for v in a if v not in a[::5]]
```

Store the unwanted value in a `set` before could lead to better perf, because `not in` method is in `O(1)` for sets:

```
unwanted = set(a[::5])
[v for v in a if v not in unwanted]
```

If the amount of data is huge, [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) could be a good substitute.

Comment: It's O(1) unless you have collision attack :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
items = [1,2,3,4]
Z = [3,4,5,6]

a = list(set(items)-set(Z))
# a =[1, 2]
```

Such as:

```
fifths = a[::5]
not_fifths = list(set(a)-set(fifths))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = [x for x in a if x not in a[::5]]
```

Comment: Can you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
[a[i-1] for i in range(1, len(a) + 1) if i % 5]
```

Basically, it checks for every position to see if it is a multiple of 5 or not. You don't have to create a set object this way.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it, without any index look up overheads.

```
result = [n for i,n in enumerate(a) if i % 5 != 0]
```