# Python find messages inside a string mixed of ascii and hex

Tags: python, hex, ascii

I try to find messages in a string mixed out of ascii which has the following format:

```
"212zp*    ���                �91238902Pressure_1,9472,Pressure_2,4251,is_usb: {0}478212zp+    ���                �91238902Pressure_1,9472,Pressure_2,4251,is_usb: {0}478212zp,    ���                �91238902Pressure_1,9472,Pressure_2,4251,is_usb: {0}478212zp-    ���               "
```

I need to decode both, the hex and the ascii messages. The messages are between `91238902` and `478212`

How can I achieve this? The string is dynamic and can contain a undefined number of messages and also errors in the headers `91238902` and `478212` can occur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use for a regular expression. here is a link to the [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=91238902(.*%3F)478212&test_string=%22212zp*%20%0B%20%10%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%10%20%10%20%0E%EF%BF%BD91238902Pressure_1%2C9472%2CPressure_2%2C4251%2Cis_usb%3A%20%7B0%7D478212zp%2B%20%0B%20%10%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%10%20%10%20%0E%EF%BF%BD91238902Pressure_1%2C9472%2CPressure_2%2C4251%2Cis_usb%3A%20%7B0%7D478212zp%2C%20%0B%20%10%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%10%20%10%20%0E%EF%BF%BD91238902Pressure_1%2C9472%2CPressure_2%2C4251%2Cis_usb%3A%20%7B0%7D478212zp-%20%0B%20%10%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%10%20%10%20%22&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0):

```
import re
x = "212zp*91238902Pressure_1,9472,Pressure_2,4251,is_usb:{0}478212zp+91238902Pressure_1,9472,Pressure_2,4251,is_usb: {0}478212zp,91238902Pressure_1,9472,Pressure_2,4251,is_usb: {0}478212zp-"

# will grab between 91238902 and 478212
# alternative regex is: (?<=91238902).*?(?=478212)
result = re.findall(r'91238902(.*?)478212', x)
```

output is a list:

```
['Pressure_1,9472,Pressure_2,4251,is_usb:{0}', 'Pressure_1,9472,Pressure_2,4251,is_usb: {0}', 'Pressure_1,9472,Pressure_2,4251,is_usb: {0}']
```

Comment: Thank you, that works perfect. How can I erease the messages from the string I read with .findall?

Comment: @HansPeterLoft,  My Pleasure! If this has answered your question, please mark this answer as accepted (only if it was answered). Can you give me clarification on what you mean by `"erase messages you read"`?

Comment: The string I reading the data from is a serial port and I append all the data I read to the string x in your example. Since the data may only arrive half when I do check for messages, I cannot throw away x after reading out the messages, but I would like to erease the messages from x I have already read.

Comment: I would try coming up with some `not in` logic. If you append to a list of messages you have already read, you can compare the two lists. [this question] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104305/finding-elements-not-in-a-list) for an example. In psuedo code it would be `if thing in one list is in the other- pass. Else - Read`