# The result of filter and list comprehension of a DataFrame column is not what I expected

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

Basically I want to find IDs that are in DataFrame A but not in DataFrame B using python. I followed the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104305/finding-elements-not-in-a-list), but the result is not what I expected.

Consider the following scenario:

```
a = pd.DataFrame(data= {"id":[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'score':[90,90,91,92,93,94,99]})
b = pd.DataFrame(data= {"id":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],'letter':['a','b','c','d','e']})
```

Doing:

```
set([x for x in a['id'] if x not in b['id']])
```

as [the post mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104305/finding-elements-not-in-a-list) suggests, gives `{5}`, which is the same when doing:

```
set(filter(lambda x: x not in b['id'], a['id']))
```

And this is not what I expected. The expected result should be an empty `set()`, which can be achieved by doing:

```
set(a["id"]) - set(b["id"])
```

Could someone explain why the above codes yield different result? It will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`b['id']` is a pandas Series object. The `in` operator will work on the `index` of pandas Series (which is 0 to 4 for dataframe `b`), not the real value. A quick fix would be:

```
set([x for x in list(a['id']) if x not in list(b['id'])]) # returns set()
```

Comment: Please don't suggest doing `in` checks on `lists`. Lists searches are O(N) in complexity.

Comment: @coldspeed That's true. IMO the OP's question isn't about how to do it. It's 'why can't I do the same thing to pandas Series as someone did (on lists) in the link?' So I'm just showing a possibility. Actually, the last line of code in the question already has a low complexity solution.