# compare two lists to get non matching elements

Tags: python, list

I checked this [comparing lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388818/how-can-i-compare-two-lists-in-python-and-return-matches), Only one answer is relative to what I am trying to do. I have to lists with some similiar elements, I want to get the non -matching elements.

```
len(h) = 1973182  #h[0] = 'B00006J8F4F2', y[0] = 'B0075Y2X2GO6'
len(y) = 656890
```

I am doing

`new_list = [i for i in h if i not in y]`,however this takes about 13 minutes to do, Is there a faster way of doing this?

In refer to "duplicate" question, [Finding elements not in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104305/finding-elements-not-in-a-list), I use the same code, What I am looking for is a faster way of doing it.

Comment: Are list elements unique?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding elements not in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104305/finding-elements-not-in-a-list)

Comment: Just to clarify - by "non-matching elements" you mean things in the first list that aren't in the second? Or thing that aren't in either?

Comment: are there duplicates in `y`?

Comment: @doctorlove  things in the first list that aren't in the second

Comment: @yatu no, all elements in the list are unique

Comment: Okay my approach should work fine in that case @programmerwiz32

Comment: Updated the answer @programmerwiz32 here `sets` with `sorted` is performing up to 200 times faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sets`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) to more efficiently find the difference between both lists. If you need to keep the order in the original list you can use `sorted` with a `key`.

We want to sort the elements in the set according to their appearance in the original list, so one way is to build a lookup dictionary. We can use `enumerate` for that. Then we only need to lookup on the dictionary as a `key` function:

```
d = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(h)}
new_list  = sorted(list((set(h) - set(y))), key = lambda x: d[x])
```

---

Let's try with a simple example:

```
y = range(5)
h = range(7)
d = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(h)}
sorted(list((set(h) - set(y))), key = lambda x: d[x])
# [5, 6]
```

---

Timings -

```
import random
y = random.sample(range(1, 10001), 10000)
h = random.sample(range(1, 20001), 10000)

%timeit [i for i in h if i not in y]
# 1.28 s ± 37.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

def using_sets(a,b):
    d = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(a)}
    sorted(list((set(a) - set(b))), key = lambda x: d[x])

%timeit using_sets(h,y)
# 6.16 ms ± 373 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

So there's a clear improvement, with the proposed approach performing up to 200 times faster.

Comment: set(h)-set(y) will give element of h which is not in h, maybe OP requrire this for both list

Comment: This will also remove any duplicates that exist within `h` i.e `h = [2, 2]`

Comment: The element in h which is not in h? This gives the set difference. Which is a more efficient way of doing `...if i not in y`

Comment: Yes that is a good point @Sayse it will if there are duplicates. Lets ask

Comment: Well aparently elements in the list are unique @sayse thanks for pointing out though

Comment: Your first link points to the deprecated `sets` module. The documentation for the newer, built-in `set` type is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set).

Comment: does your update indicate that my initial method is faster ?

Comment: No @programmerwiz32 mine is 200 times faster. So its `1.28s/6.16ms = 207`

Comment: @yatu i got just a little faster thna yours 6.16/5.44=1.13

Comment: Nice @prashantrana :) Nice soln using defaultdict

Comment: Gettiing 1.04 in my machine. So its safe to say that performance-wise they're about the same @prashantrana

Comment: @yatu yes performance waise ,same , maybe machine dependent and I am using python3.7

Comment: @yatu just check out a little more improve solution 6.16/2.75 = 2.24

Answer (score 1):

The answer you linked to suggests using sets, because they use hashes to look thing up quickly.
With lists, and `in`, like

```
new_list = [i for i in h if i not in y]
```

the whole of list `y` needs checking each time for each `i` in `h`.

You could use sets, but as has been pointed out need to be careful with duplicates getting lost.

You could use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
```

the with two lists, say

```
l1 = [1,1,2,3,4]
l2 = [3,3,4,5,6]
```

for examples' sake, can use fed into a Counter each

```
>>> Counter(l1)
Counter({1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1})
>>> Counter(l2)
Counter({3: 2, 4: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1})
```

This just walks each list once.
Subtracting them gives what's in the first but not the second:

```
>>> Counter(l1)-Counter(l2)
Counter({1: 2, 2: 1})
```

The `elements` tell you what you want

```
>>> diff = Counter(l1)-Counter(l2)
>>> list(diff.elements())
[1, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

using programmatically and keep order and handle duplicate in list1

```
def function(list1, list2):
    dic2={}   
    for i in list2:
        try:
            if i in dic2.keys():
                pass
        except KeyError:
            dic2[i]=1           

    result =[]
    for i in list1:
        try:
            if i in dic2.keys():
                pass
        except:
            result.append(i)
    return result



list1=[1,2,2,3]
list2=[3,4,5]

solution = function(list1,list2)
print(solution)
```

output

```
[1, 2, 2]
```

using @yatu h,y list, here is time result

```
%timeit function(h,y)
2.75 ms ± 22.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: how is this faster than `new_list  = sorted((set(h) - set(y)), key = h.index)` ?

Comment: @programmerwiz32   because i didn't sort the object which will took O(nlogn) time and then do calculation to preserve index,  here i just hashed value of list2 in dictionary so O(1) time to access it , and O(n) TIME to go through list1, so complexity becomes `O(n)`,

Comment: @programmerwiz32 see current one solution , check speed and if you find it good one than accept and upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Counter class from collections:

```
list1 = [1,1,2,3,4]
list2 = [3,3,4,5,6]

from collections import Counter
result = list((Counter(list1)-Counter(list2)).elements())

# [1, 1, 2]
```

Or, if you want mutual exclusion:

```
count1 = Counter(list1)
count2 = Counter(list2)
r = list((count1-count2+(count2-count1)).elements()) 

# [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```